# How to open a new tab with the content and the container together if using ajax load to get the content?

Tags: php, ajax, tabs, load

I have a php page with a nav and a content div. When I choose an option in the nav, the content is modified by loading another php file inside it. For this I use ajax with load function. My problem is that if I  right click and select open in a new tab or a new window, evidently, only the content is open in the tab.

I know that I can have the whole page (container + content) in each php file and load only the content div, but I think there is no much sense in this.

Is there any way to get the container along the content in the new tab?

Comment: in that php file with the content, check if it an ajax request, if it is display the content, if not then display the whole thing

Comment: The whole thing are two php files, the main file, and the dinamycally loaded file inside the content, Then, does I have to detect if it's not ajax, set the content and say it not to load the inner file, but the main one? @David Lavieri

Comment: I made up the idea in [github](https://gist.github.com/falmar/4889263ce3187d0bf1a8ea1690b34d08) you maybe understand it better

Comment: Thanks, What I really don't understand is how to say my php if new tab (url access) don't load, but execute this function to load the whole thing. If it was one file without dinamyc content, I would use a header and that would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I already had a similar situation, the tabs have pages, and the menu was in the top page. you can apply this solution:

This logic will work with iframe, if you are using divs, you can adjust for this:

main page with the nav menu, here you need apply some logic like this:

```
<script>
        //Object to get values of URL (GET)
        var request = {
            get get() {
                var vars = {};
                if (window.location.search.length !== 0)
                    window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
                        key = decodeURIComponent(key);
                        if (typeof vars[key] === "undefined") {
                            vars[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
                        }
                        else {
                            vars[key] = [].concat(vars[key], decodeURIComponent(value));
                        }
                    });
                return vars;
            },
            getParam: function (param) {
                var vars = request.get;
                if (vars[param] != undefined) {
                    return vars[param];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

            }, getParams: function () {
                return request.get;
            }
        };
        //variable that defines if the client are in mainWindow
        window.mainWindowFrame = true;

        var tabName = request.getParam("tab");
        console.log("tabName",tabName);


        //call some function to reload the content of iframe or div to requested tab.
        //if(tabName != null || tabName != ""){
        //tabs.load(tabName) ....
        //}
    </script>
```

In the pages of content you need aplly this piece of code to reload the page if the menu are not present:

```
<script>
        //name of this tab
        var tabName = "someTab";
        //check if the menu are present here
        if(window.top.mainWindowFrame == undefined){
            window.location.href = "mainpage.html?tab="+tabName;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I have to modify my code, becaus my main page doesn't use the parameter to set the content. I just take the src of the element who fire the event and insert it into the div. If I change that, this should work, so I'll give it a try. Thanks.